# django redirect does not work

Tags: django, redirect

I wanted to have function that every time get the request and check that user is login and then return user object if user is login otherwise redirect to login , so this is what I tried to do

```
def is_login(request):
    userID = request.session.get('mainSession', 0)
    next = resolve(request.path_info).url_name
    print(1)
    if userID != 0:
        print(2)
        user = msignup.objects.filter(id=userID).first()
        return user
    print(3)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login') + "?next=
{}".format(next))
```

I tried to test this function with below view when user is loged out and request has no mainSession :

```
def email_activation(request):
    user = is_login(request)
    print(4)
    email = user.email
    return render(request, 'account/emailActivation.html',{'email': 
email})
```

and in response I got this :
'HttpResponseRedirect' object has no attribute 'email'

and the response for prints that I had made is :

- 1
- 3
- 4

  why after 3 redirect does  not happens ?what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why should it? You call `is_login` from `email_activation`, and it returns a redirect object. But the view then carries on with the rest of the code that you have written.

Comment: so is there any way that I make this redirect happen?if no what is ur suggestion for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all. Django has a few ways to do this built-in. I strongly recomend you to use something that's already made. The login_required decorator would work great for your use case.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required

Now, if what you're doing is an experiment. The problem that you have is that you are returning the response Redirect object on is_login. What you could to do to make this work (i again recommend you to not go with this route), is make another function that redirects to the login page, and have the is_login function just return True or False if the user is login or not.

Then you will be able to do something like:

```
if not is_login(request):
   return redirectToSigninPage(request)
```

Comment: we do not use django built in User model ,so I cant use this login_required decorator ,and I am agree with u writing seccond function is not like a proper solution